# Cant initialise thread in Xcode , C++11

Tags: xcode, multithreading, c++11, boost

I am trying to implement spsc_queue of boost.

But initialising thread throws error. I cant use both std::thread as well as boost thread.

sharedQueue.hpp
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
using namespace std;
class sharedQueue
{
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<int> lockFreeQ{100};

std::queue<int> comQue;
int head =0;;
int tail = 0;

public:

sharedQueue();

std::mutex lockForQueue;

void write(int writeValue);
int read();

void startTesting();

void TestWrite(int MaxElement);

void lockFreeProduce();
void lockFreeConsume();
void TestLockFreeQueue();    
};`
```

Following is the sharedQueue.cpp

```
#include "sharedQueue.hpp"
 int sharedQueue :: read(){    
int readValue;
lockForQueue.lock();
if(!(comQue.empty()))
{
readValue = comQue.front();
comQue.pop();
}
lockForQueue.unlock();
return readValue;
}

void sharedQueue :: write(int writeValue){
lockForQueue.lock();

comQue.push(writeValue);
tail++;
lockForQueue.unlock();
} 

void sharedQueue:: startTesting(){

std::cout<<"Size of the que --"<<comQue.size()<<std::endl;
}

void sharedQueue:: TestWrite(int maxEle ){

for(int i = 0 ; i < maxEle; i ++){
    write(i);
}
}
void sharedQueue::lockFreeProduce(){

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    cout <<“Produced--    "<< i<<endl;
    lockFreeQ.push(i);
}
}
void sharedQueue::lockFreeConsume(){

for(int i = 0;  i <10; i++){
    lockFreeQ.front();

   cout << “  Consume-- "<<lockFreeQ.pop();    
}
}
void sharedQueue:: TestLockFreeQueue(){

std::thread t1(lockFreeProduce);

std::thread t2(lockFreeConsume);

t1.join();
t2.join();  
} `
```

I am using Xcode. I have tried changing 
C++ Language dialect to c++11 from GNU++11
Standard Library to libc++11 from libstdC++

Please help.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error ? And why do you want to use both boost thread and the one provided by your standard library impl ?

Comment: No matching constructor to initialisation of boost::thread.  I tried to create thread using boost as well as standard thread. But both throws the same error.

Comment: Try `std::thread t1([this] () { this-> lockFreeProduce(); });`

Comment: Yes it works fine now.  could you please explain me the problem. and “[this] () { this-> lockFreeProduce(); }” this structure?

Comment: Have added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a member function as a new thread, not a plain old function. The syntax for member function is different.

```
void sharedQueue:: TestLockFreeQueue(){
    std::thread t1(std::bind(&sharedQueue::lockFreeProduce, this));
    std::thread t2(std::bind(&sharedQueue::lockFreeConsume, this));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();  
}
```

Below answer assumes that we are talking about `non-static` member function. `static` member function behaves kind of same way as that of a normal function pointer.

A member function pointer is complex than a plain old function pointer and it cannot be invoked in standalone manner i.e it can only be called when there is an object instance of that class.

[See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25d4855f9e6ca413) for an example and [read this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) for better understanding of member function pointers.

An easier way to do it i.e instead of using `bind` to create a callable object is to use a lambda, C++11 onwards and you should prefer lambda over bind whenever and however possible.

Your example using a lambda:

```
void sharedQueue:: TestLockFreeQueue(){
   std::thread t1([this]() { this->lockFreeProduce(); });
   std::thread t2([this]() { this->lockFreeConsume(); });

   t1.join();
   t2.join();  
}
```

Here I am passing a `lambda` to the constructor of the thread which creates an anonymous functor structure. The square bracket `[...]` is the capture list which copies `this` pointer so that it can be used inside a lambda.

More about lambda can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11).